# Cannot zip a mutli-part archive, zip -FF command failing with out of memory error

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

Command `zip -FF xxx.zip --out final_xxx.zip` Fails with *zip error out of memory* or *zip error : cannot split, read, write, file is too big.may be result of bad comrpression , try -fz*

I do not how try with `-fz`

Note :

1. I have made xxx.zip file by concatenating multipart archive xxx.z01,xxx.z02...xxx.z08,yyy.zip file using the command: `cat xxx.z01 xxx.z02...xxx.z08 yyy.zip>xxx.zip`.
2. Each xxx.z0* file is 2GB in size and the end marker yyy.zip is around 1
   GB, so the final xxx.zip file is 17GB.
3. I am zipping using -FF to remove any damage so I can unzip it then.
   Please suggest how to work it out in such a case.

I have tried zipping by taking one z01 at a time too, example- `cat xxx.z01 yyy.zip>xxx.zip` and then `zip -FF xxx.zip --out final_xxx.zip` but it still fails with the same error.

PS:I have used the same method of concatenating  then zipping using -FF and then unzipping earlier with comparatively smaller size and it worked perfectly fine.

OS: ubuntu 16.0

VMWare RAM: 8 GB

Files: Informatica 10.1.0 Installation